# Generate multiple nested for loops based on number of hyperparameters

Tags: python, for-loop, python-itertools

I have augmentation methods to augment a given data set. These augmentation methods have different number of hyperparameters. Now I want to implement a generic Jupyter Notebook to iterate through the different hyperparameters to load the correct data set and train a neural network:

```
dir_data_set = "..."
data_set_name = "..."
start_value_hyperparameters = [] # list of int
step_sizes = [] # list of int
number_of_steps = [] # list of int
```

now based on the variables above I want to generate the following nested for-loops assuming we have three hyperparameters for the augmentation method (example)

```
for i in range(0, number_of_steps[0]):
    hyperparameter_1 = start_value_hyperparameters[0] + i*step_sizes[0]
    for j in range(0, number_of_steps[1]):
        hyperparameter_2 = start_value_hyperparameters[1] + j*step_sizes[1]
        for k in range(0, number_of_steps[2]):
            hyperparameter_3 = start_value_hyperparameters[2] + k*step_sizes[2]
            df = load_df_from_pickle_file(dir_data_set + data_set_name.format(hyperparameter_1, hyperparameter_2, hyperparameter_3))
            # train the net/some code
```

How would I achieve this?

Comment: Maybe you can use `product` from `itertools` module or use `GridSearchCV` from `sklearn`

Comment: @Corralien Thanks for the hint. I think I will precalculate the values and put them in a list and iterate over that list.